# Bound or bounded?

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

> Part of the problem is that the justices are not `_5_` by an ethics code.
>
> Choice:
>   5. [A]advanced   [B]caught   [C]bound   [D]founded

By the meaning of this sentence, the choice should be C, the meaning I think is something like `limit`.

If this is not one multiple choice, could it be right to use `caught`? Because `be caught by` is one possible usage.

And as you see, the other three choices are all in past tense.
So could it be right to use `bounded` as one verb?

Here maybe `bound` is an adjective means limited or obliged? 
However, `bounded` could also be an adjective means limited?

Anything wrong in my comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar problem to that in your [previous question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/split-along-idealogical-lines-meaning): *bound* here is the past participle of *bind*:

> **Bound ...
>
>    2** forced to do something by law, duty or a particular situation
>    **bound by something** *We are not bound by the decision*
>   [(Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary)](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bound)

So:

> Part of the problem is that the justices are not compelled to act in accordance with an ethics code.

The construction *BE VERB<sub>past participle</sub>* is not a past tense but a passive. However, in cases like this, it is impossible to distinguish between a past participle used in a passive construction and the same past participle used as an adjective: it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: oh,,,god, I haven't thought of `Bind`